# Plugin-file minimum requirements for hooking into wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-hook

I'm relatively new to working with WP. In my main plugin file, I have a couple of hooks working. I have another file that I'm trying to add an **add_action()** to, but it keeps coming back as undefined.

What are the basic requirements for a file to hook into WP?

```
add_action('init', 'loop_users');
function loop_users() {
    $users = get_users();
    //execute code here
}
```

When i use this add_action or any other WP hook it always returns as undefined. Thoughts?

Comment: Please post the error message you are getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress Plugin Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243873/wordpress-plugin-development)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you are having problems with your code, please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If this is all your code then you haven't really are missing quite a bit, and there are many guides and tutorials online to show you how to develop a plugin. Please take a look at at some of these and if you run into specific problems with the code, you can come back and give us the details so we can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can include your other files to your main plugin file using include statement. For example if your main plugin file and another file are in the same directory.
`include dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/yourfile';`